# Undefined reference to leveldb Options

Tags: c++, leveldb

I'm trying to use leveldb in our project. I declare an Options as a member of my class using

```
leveldb::Options options;
```

At the top I include the appropriate files:

```
#include "leveldb/db.h"
#include "leveldb/options.h"
```

But when I compile I get this:

```
undefined reference to `leveldb::Options::Options()'
```

I'm not having any trouble including these, and in that `options.h` file there is an explicitly declared `Options()` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/include/leveldb/options.h`

Doesn't contain an implementation of `leveldb::Options::Options()`, just the declaration (as you said), so linking will fail.

`/util/options.cc` contains it, you need to compile it too.

Comment: Gotcha. I compiled it and I added -L lib to my makefile, and I have the entire leveldb project in the lib directory, but for some reason it's still not working. Is there something else I have to do to link it?

Comment: U got to compile everything u use and is not header only. Sorry, cant give u further input. I just found the issue by googling it ;) I'd just compile the whole leveldb project unless u rly worry about compilation speed

Comment: Well I DID compile the whole project. I think I'm just having trouble linking it. Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: I figured it out. If anyone from the future reads this: I forgot the -lleveldb in the Makefile.

Comment: @RaidenWorley is it possible to share your Makefile? I'm having exactly the same problem.